# I need to get paypal confirmation to php

Tags: php, paypal

I need to get paypal APN to be convert to php so that I can get mysql database updated with sales.Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Are you looking for someone to code this for you?

Comment: Because in that case there are many quality programmers looking for jobs at jobs.stackoverflow.com. Quality Programmers, at a Quality Site! (That was suppose to sound corny)

Answer (score 3):

The Paypal API [code samples page](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/code_samples) includes PHP examples.